# A question about the representation of coordinates with respect to different bases.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ and $B'$ be separate basis matrices for a vector space $V$. Each column is a separate basis element.

Let $X$ be $X'$ be the coordinates for the same vector $v\in V$ in terms of the bases $B$ and $B'$ respectively. Also, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $BP=B'$.

Now $BX=B'P^{-1}X$. Hence, we should have $P^{-1}X=X'$. *However, Artin says $PX=X'$*. I can't understand why this is.

Comment: Yea, that looks like an error to me.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comment above.*

You are right, it should be $P^{-1}X = X'$. This is a mistake by Artin.